# XML/XSL: Check if ID exists, then add CLASS to other element

Tags: xml, xslt

If I have a code along these lines..

```
<code id="hello">
<tag>
<moretags>...</moretags>
</tag>
</code>
```

Compared to a code as such:

```
<code id="hello">
<tag>
<moretags id="joker">...</moretags>
</tag>
</code>
```

Can I have (*in my file.xsl*) a rule that works like this:

**if id="joker" appears** (in the HTML file with the file.xsl template)
**then add class="world" to the thing with id="hello"**

If yes, what would that rule look like?

*Me: total novice. Trying to get into things. Tried to explain to a friend what I meant. Couldn't make myself understood. Now that I know how to phrase my question - friend 's not around. Hope you can help me out. 
Browsed through StackOverflow... but since I hardly know how frame my question I don't know what to browse for. I'm certain the answer's (in all likelyhood annoylingly simple to most and) already here somewhere. If so, please link. Thank you.*

Answer (score 0):

In XSLT, a rule is called *template*. So, you would write a template that matches this element:

```
 <xsl:template match="*[@id = 'hello' and //*[@id='joker']]">
```

and then copy it and add another attribute:

```
<xsl:copy>
   <xsl:attribute name="class" select="'world'"/>
```

But you also need to account for other attributes of this element, and then process the remainder of nodes.

**XML Input**

```
<code id="hello">
<tag>
<moretags id="joker">...</moretags>
</tag>
</code>
```

**Stylesheet**

The only other template rule in this stylesheet is the so-called identity transform, which simply produces a faithful copy of the input XML.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<xsl:transform xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="2.0">
    <xsl:output method="xml" omit-xml-declaration="yes" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes" />

    <xsl:template match="*[@id = 'hello' and //*[@id='joker']]">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@*"/>
            <xsl:attribute name="class" select="'world'"/>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="node()"/>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="@*|node()">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:transform>
```

**XML Output**

```
<code id="hello" class="world">
   <tag>
      <moretags id="joker">...</moretags>
   </tag>
</code>
```

Answer (score 0):

> Now that I know how to phrase my question

I wouldn't go that far... However, if we can restate the problem as:

*For any element that:

 • has an attribute `id`="hello"; **AND**

• has a descendant element with an attribute `id`="joker",

add an attribute `class`="world",*

then you could try:

**XSLT 1.0**

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" 
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>
<xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

<!-- identity transform -->
<xsl:template match="@*|node()">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="@id[.='hello'][..//@id='joker']">
    <xsl:copy-of select="."/>
    <xsl:attribute name="class">world</xsl:attribute>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```